# ssh find command and store

Tags: bash, ssh, find, remote-access

im trying to capture a find outcome within a batch script
it works fine until i add another word
example alien (works)
alien 1 (not working)

```
found201=$(ssh root@192.168.1.201 find "${folder201[@]}" ! -path "*/.wdmc/*" -type f -iname "*$ffind*" | sort)
```

if i run in a terminal

```
found201=$(ssh root@192.168.1.201 'find /shares/Public/ /shares/Videos/ -type f -iname "*alien 1*"' | sort)
```

with 'find .....' it works but nothing is  plus its not using string/array

when i add '' to script get bad substitution (assuming it now treats as a string not a command)

i need to use find as later i need to delete files etc in a set manner

how can i add '   ' to find and use strings/array

---

running normally get this

```
++ ssh root@192.168.1.201 find /shares/Public/ /shares/Videos/ '' '!' -path '*/.wdmc/*' -type f -iname '*alien 1*'
++ sort
find: unrecognized: 1*
```

Comment: What does the command output if you run it without the `=$()` part?

Comment: found201=ssh root@192.168.1.201 find "${folder201[@]}" ! -path "*/.wdmc/*" -type f -iname "*$ffind*" | sort


                                                                   get root@192.168.1.201: command not found                                                 


                            adding ' to beging and end 
  
                                                    find: unrecognized: 1*

Comment: Uh no, just the `ssh '...'`.  You can't use `found201=` like that.

Comment: on it own i get same issue unless i hard code the string/array then it works or if just type alien instead of alien 1

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, enclosing the entire `find` command within double-quotes, and using single-quotes inside:

```
found201=$(ssh root@192.168.1.201 "find ${folder201[@]} ! -path '*/.wdmc/*' -type f -iname '*$ffind*'" | sort)
```

However there is a caveat:
this won't work with folders in `${folder201[@]}` that contain spaces.

Comment: find is not been sent properly when using ssh

Comment: ++ ssh root@192.168.1.201 find /shares/Public/ /shares/Videos/ '' '!' -path '*/.wdmc/*' -type f -iname '*alien 1*'
find: unrecognized: 1*

Comment: @user1184628 I see, I misunderstood your question at first. I rewrote my answer, hope this helps, let me know if not

Comment: ++ ssh root@192.168.1.201 'find '\''/shares/Public/' /shares/Videos/ ''\'' ! -path '\''*/.wdmc/*'\'' -type f -iname '\''*alien 1*'\'''
++ sort
find: /shares/Public/ /shares/Videos/ : No such file or directory

Comment: it now treats shares/Public/ /shares/Videos/ as one folder not two

Comment: I see, my bad. Btw there's a caveat btw, see my update

Answer (score -1):

think i have sorted it

```
found201=$(ssh root@192.168.1.201 "find ${folder201[@]} ! -path '*/.wdmc/*' -type f -iname '*$ffind*'" | sort)
```

changed '${folder201[@]}' to ${folder201[@]} (removed single quotes)